# Symfony Doctrine entity property with array of objects

Tags: doctrine, symfony4

I have a survey form that is mapped to an entity.
Within this form, there is a multiple-choice field.
Choices/Options are Entity Type.

Survey Form Entity property:

```
    /**
     * @var App\Entity\Definition[]|ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\Column(type="simple_array")
     */
    protected $dissatisfactionReasons;
```

What I want to do is save the selected choices without using the relation table (ManyToMany).
I simply want to save `$dissatisfactionReasons` property into the table as an array of IDs.
I also defined `__toString()` method for `Definition` entity:

```
/**
     * @return string
     */
    public function __toString()
    {
        return (string)$this->getId();
    }
```

Using this code I was able to save `$dissatisfactionReasons` property values as a string of IDs separated by a comma. However, on retrieving survey form Entity `$dissatisfactionReasons` property contains an array of integers and not converted/mapped back to an array of `Definition` entities.

Using `@ORM\Column(type="array")` instead of `simple_array` works as expected, but type array serializes whole Definition entity data whereas I only want to save IDs

Comment: Why not use a ManyToMany relation?? Without it you just have to do a lot of extra work, just as you are seeing. You'll have to manually go get the array of `Definition` entities on your own with your approach. Silly to do that when it's the entire point of the `ManyToMany` relationship.

Comment: ManyToMany creates extra table. I don't want another table to keep only dissatisfaction reasons because there are won't be any query related to it. I mean there will not be query saying bring me all users with specific dissatisfactionReason. it is just for storing. Viewing will be only in the survey form detail page.

Comment: Not sure why you care if there is an extra table. But, that’s your choice. You will just have to do the extra work in your code to compensate.